# Reference on size 1 std vector from coefficient reference

Tags: c++, vector, reference

Let's say we have a

```
class X
{
private:
    std::vector<double> & values_;
public:
    X(std::vector<double> & values) : values_(values) {}
};
```

and that I want to create a class `Y` deriving from `X` and with a ctor

```
Y(double & value) : X(/* something /*) {}
```

with `values` reference to a size 1 vector with only coefficient equal to `value`.

I don't see how to do this nor if it is possible

Comment: `+= 0.01;` ? typo?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai indeed, corrected

Comment: Unrelated: Having a reference member is usually not a good idea.

Comment: This is, indeed, not possible.  A single `double` is very different from a `std::vector<double>` containing one element.

Comment: What's your programming background? If it's an OO language or C, leave that - along with your shoes - behind the door. Only then you shall enter the realm of C++

Comment: Your problem might be solvable if `X` had a `std::span<double>` member (if `X` doesn't need to resize the vector)

Comment: *"a size 1 vector with only coefficient equal to `value`."* -- Equal to `value` or a reference to `value`? There is a huge difference. The latter is impossible since `X` does not support a vector of references, and the former brings into question why `value` is accepted by non-`const` reference (instead of by value).

Comment: @Artyer `X` doesn't have an `std::span<double>` data member but does never resize the the vector.

Comment: @11house I meant change the vector reference to be a `std::span` member, like: https://godbolt.org/z/GhKcraMn8

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly easy, and impossible. `Y` will need to have a non-reference `std::vector<double> values` member, and initialize that vector with the single argument.

Because `X` can change the length of `values`, setting it to e.g. 0 or 2, it's clear that such changes to `values` cannot be propagated back to the `double&`.

I suspect that `X` really should have had a `std::span<double>`. You can create a span to both a `std::vector<double>` and a single `double`. But note that resizing the `vector` can invalidate the `span`.

Comment: So I should use pointer instead of reference ?

Comment: @11house: That makes absolutely zero difference. If the `X::foo` method calls`values.resize(2)`, what do you expect to happen to `double& value` ? You have a design problem here, not (yet) a C++ problem.

Comment: Ok, I understand the design big flaw I have. My current question stems from this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77647551/refactoring-a-parameter-class?noredirect=1#comment136890145_77647551, I can give details if needed